# How to migrate Firebase to version 12.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

Im currently update Firebase version to 12.0.0 from older version, but after compiling gradle, that was showing an error message

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL7RW.jpg)
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilt5s.jpg)

What wrong with Gradle implementation of new Firebase library?

Code build.gradle -> app

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:12.0.0'
```

and at bottom of build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Code build.gradle -> root Project

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
}}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/" }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/rilixtech/maven" }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}}
```

Message error from console

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-license:12.0.0.
```

Comment: What is your classpath in root level gradle.

Comment: Please post your code and error messages as text and not as images.

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

Comment: @SuryaAdiputra you don't have allprojects {} tag in your root gradle ?